# @onchange in odoo is not working properly

Tags: odoo-10

I have two models `main.channel` and `sub.channel`

`main.channel` has many2many relationship with `sub.channel`

`sale.order` has many2many relationship with both `main.channel` and `sub.channel`

Now in sale order I want that if I select a `main.channel` record then all records in `sub.channel` object that belongs to selected `main.channel` record should be fetched automatically.

I have done this functionality, but after fetching records when I click on save button, all child(`sub.channel`) records seems missing and not saved.

I have tried this by many different ways but I have not found proper solution for this yet

Below is my code that I have written in `sale.order`.

```
@api.onchange("main_channel_ids")
def sub_ids_values(self):
    for rec in self:
        sub_channels_list=[]
        for main_channel in rec.main_channel_ids:
            for sub_channel in main_channel.sub_channel_ids:
                sub_channels_list.append(sub_channel.id)
        #rec.sub_channel_ids = [(6,0,sub_channels_list)] #this is also not working
        rec..write({'sub_channel_ids': [(6, 0, sub_channels_list)]})
```

Comment: Your code using the commented line instead of `write` will work. The issue is not in this method.

Comment: Yes i also tried this way but still problem is there

Comment: The problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can write as following :

```
@api.onchange("main_channel_ids")
def sub_ids_values(self):
    for rec in self:
        sub_channels = rec.main_channel_ids.mapped('sub_channel_ids')
        rec.sub_channel_ids = sub_channels
```

Comment: Thanks firstly ....This will fetch all sub_channels automatically ... its fine but when i click on save button, all sub_channels seems missing and this problem is still there